# Custom Siri Intent Generation broken in Xcode Version 11.4 (11E146)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sirishortcuts, xcode11.4

I updated Xcode yesterday only to discover that my custom siri intents no longer seem to generate. I started seeing others with this issue on the Apple dev forum this morning https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/130691 and thought I would ask here if anyone found a solution for this. When I visit build settings, there no longer seems to be a setting to select the intent generation language with the "intent class generation language". Target membership on the intent is good and again, this built yesterday before updating and has not been altered for months. Does anyone know if rewriting all the custom intents will fix this (that's what I am going to try next) or if there is some new setting / plist entry that needs to be updated to get this working again. I will update here if I find the solution. Also to note, I was generating my intent files in Objective C.

Comment: Hey there, i'm the one who reported it on the Apple forums. I actually made a thread here too already. Lets hope Apple gets back to us!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60862481/my-app-does-not-find-sirikit-intentdefinition-classes-in-xcode-11-4

Comment: I like the response you got on your question. I didn't think to compile on command line. I am just downgrading xcode. Crazy they let this go out.

Answer (score 0):

I have dug around, and also talked to Apple Support. Turns out, it has to do with the "legacy build system".

Once i switched to the new build system in xcode project settings, i could build the project again.

You could argue that it should work if they still support the legacy system (which they do), but oh well.

Read how to switch here:
https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev396bc94c7