# How to import the Swift classes generated by the Intents Definition File from Objective-C?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, sirikit, sirishortcuts

After defining my Intents Definition File I can access the Swift generated classes in my Intents Extension

[image]

Also I've ensured the generated classes are members of the main app target.

[image]

In the intent handler I can see it's properly defined

[image]

Pointing to this declaration

[image]

I don't really understand where this file is located, is it generated at compile time? In any case, in my app delegate I would like to handle this intent like so

[image]

But it's not imported, how do I link it to the main app target?

Comment: Looks like it might be related https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847166/1376627

Comment: What a problem to use `IntentHandler` in the `AppDelegate`? As I can see it performs the same code and doesn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

It's generated.

Just define a protocol for the generated class

```
protocol CreateReminderConfig {}
```

And add the following in swift:

```
extension CreateReminderIntent: CreateReminderConfig {}
```

Then, compare the class to match the protocol instead of that class.

That class is generated and it might be not the same as a normal class in switch or the visibility/usage is limited.

Comment: Could you be a bit more verbose please as I am new to iOS development. Thanks. Will try and give it a go nonetheless when I get a chance.

Comment: It seems that the headers for the generated files (or the files) are not included into the "..-Swift.h" header. You need either 1) your own classes can are available from ObjC, 2) Import these headers manually, 3) Switch to swift language.